# XSLT- break list what there is special node in the list-item

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Here is a xml I have.

```
<doc>
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>*</label>
            <p>text1</p>
            <list list-type="order">
                <list-item>
                    <label>**</label>
                    <p>text2</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>***</label>
                    <p>text3</p>
                    <non-normative-note>non-normative-text</non-normative-note> 
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>****</label>
                    <p>text4</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>*****</label>
                    <p>text5</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>******</label>
                    <p>text6</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>*******</label>
            <p>text7</p>
            <list list-type="order">
                <list-item>
                    <label>********</label>
                    <p>text8</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>*********</label>
                    <p>text9</p>
                </list-item>
                <list-item>
                    <label>**********</label>
                    <p>text10</p>
                </list-item>
            </list>
        </list-item>
    </list>
</doc>
```

I need to break nest lists from their parent and need to break the list if there is `<non-normative-note>` node in the `<list-item>`

Here is my expected output,

```
<doc>
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>*</label>
            <p>text1</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
    <list list-type="order">
        <list-item>
            <label>**</label>
            <p>text2</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>***</label>
            <p>text3</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
    <p><non-normative-note>non-normative-text</non-normative-note> </p>
    <list list-type="order">
        <list-item>
            <label>****</label>
            <p>text4</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>*****</label>
            <p>text5</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>******</label>
            <p>text6</p>
        </list-item>
    </list> 
    <list list-type="alpha-lower">
        <list-item>
            <label>*******</label>
            <p>text7</p>
        </list-item>
    </list>
    <list list-type="order">
        <list-item>
            <label>********</label>
            <p>text8</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>*********</label>
            <p>text9</p>
        </list-item>
        <list-item>
            <label>*********</label>
            <p>text10</p>
        </list-item>
    </list> 
</doc>
```

Here is the XSLT I have now,

```
<xsl:template match="list[descendant::list]">
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="@list-type"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="list-item">
            <list list-type="{$type}">
                <list-item>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::list)]"/>
                </list-item>
            </list>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="list"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

This breaks nested lists successfully and I need to extend this to break list when there is a `<non-normative-note>`. Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xsl:for-each-group` here, with `group-ending-with` to enable your breaking....

Try adding these two templates to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="list">
    <xsl:variable name="type" select="@list-type"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="list-item" group-ending-with="*[non-normative-note]">
        <list list-type="{$type}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </list>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="list-item[non-normative-note]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except non-normative-note" />
    </xsl:copy>
    <p><xsl:copy-of select="non-normative-note" /></p>
</xsl:template>
```